# Track menu link clicks in Wordpress with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I would like to track how many people click on a link in the menu bar and where did they come from. Is there a way to do it? I see that in Wordpress there is a class called menu-item, but I don't know how this would help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics will track where users come from by default. Because of this, you only need to create an event to fire on the click class: menu-item.

After setting up event tracking, navigate to Behaviour -> Events -> Top Events. Once at this page, search for the naming of the event you created, and then select a secondary dimension such as Default Channel Grouping, Source/Medium, or whatever is relevant to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to create universal event tag. In fields to set, choose variable `refferer` and as value select `{{refferer}}`.

2) Create "click classes" variable with value: `gtm.elementClasses`

3) Create trigger of "Click - All Elements" type. Select "some clicks" and fill it with: `{{click classes}}` equals `menu-item`.